# How to trigger function on false?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I have an input form that I want to validate email adresses (or just an @ sign). But I only want validation when it's wrong, so remove everything from before the else statement in the jquery snippet?

**EDIT**

**When the user input is wrong, in this case not an emailadress, inform the user.**

**HTML**

```
<form onsubmit="validate(); return false;">
<p>Enter an email address:</p>
<input id="email">
<button type="submit" id="validate">Validate!</button>
</form>
<br>
<h2 id="result"></h2>
```

**jQuery**

```
function validateEmail(email) {       
    var re = /@/;
    return re.test(email);
}

function validate(){
  $("#result").text("");
  var email = $("#email").val();
  if (validateEmail(email)) {
    $("#result").text(email + " is valid :)");
    $("#result").css("color", "green");
  } else {
    $("#result").text(email + "is not valid :(");
    $("#result").css("color", "red");
  }
  return false;
}

$("form").bind("submit", validate);
```

Comment: give input type as email it will automatically take care of validation

Comment: I want to give the user info when input it's wrong

Comment: you want to show him a popup if its not valid right..

Comment: No I do this $("#result").text(email + "is not valid :("); on <h2 id="result"></h2>

Comment: What exactly you mean by `"But I only want validation when it's wrong..."`
That is what validations are for. 
When ever user submits the form, you validate the submission. It either fails or pass. Sorry to say, but I didn't get the question

Comment: @RaviTiwari I'll edit 1 sec

Comment: @RaviTiwari When the user input is wrong, in this case not an emailadress, then inform the user.

Comment: @RaviTiwari I don't know how to manipulate the code to only do that part

Comment: I think what you're trying to do is to show an error only if the field isn't empty? If so, you can change the regex: var re = /@|^$/;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use not operator `!` to reverse the condition like this:

```
function validate(){
  $("#result").text("");
  var email = $("#email").val();
  if (!validateEmail(email)) { //email is invalid?
    $("#result").text(email + "is not valid :(");
    $("#result").css("color", "red");
    //call a function to trigger
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: How do I remove this part:  $("#result").text(email + " is valid :)");
    $("#result").css("color", "green");

Comment: You can hide using delay.

Comment: My function is wrong, just want to give info when email is wrong, not when it's correct

Comment: Updated as per your comment. Let me know if that is what you wanted.

Comment: In that case you can only use if clause to handle as :

if (!validateEmail(email)) {
    $("#result").text(email + "is not valid :(");
    $("#result").css("color", "red");
    return false;
}